# Legend symbol angle in ArcMap 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, arcgis-10.3, legend

I work on a map with rotate data frame. When I create the legend, the symbol line in the layers on the legend are angle to different directions than the layers in the map:

[image: map example]

I try to find a way (automatically) to straight the symbol lines in the legend items as it in the map. I don't want to use the option of turn the legend to graphic elements, and then to angle the line of the symbol items to the same direction as the layers.

For clarity, this question as been asked in [GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/169058), but I didn't got suitable answer.

Comment: It would probably help if you can say what software you are trying to use.

Comment: pls provide the link to GeoNet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use clone layer with modified angle of hash lines. Show clone in the legend, show original in the view:
[image]

UPDATE:

If this

[image]

is NOT what you guys call dynamic legend, quit reading this.

Otherwise use it in addition to:

[image]

Comment: you right, but when i create fictitious layer out the data frame-when using dynamic legend option -the fictitious layer not shown.

Comment: See options for showong items in legend

Comment: For a dynamic legend hide the clone behind/under the original or other map data.

Comment: @FelixIP that's what I call a dynamic legend http://i.imgur.com/eTyp37L.png It just shoes class which are visible in current extent.

Answer (score 3):

I just could reproduce that issue. I was not aware of it before. Three things you can do to avoid it:

1. Create a **clone** (*as [point out](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/171908/53268) from @FelixIP*) or an **empty feature** just for showing purpose. *For a [dynamic legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AH1jF.png) hide the clone behind/under the original or other map data.* [image: example legend clone]
2. Just **don't** change the map rotation angle (*for somebody how handle a lot of maps it is always easier to read a north oriented map*).
3. **Convert the map into a graphic** (*personally I don't like that way, as it is not longer connected to the data of the map*).

   - Therefor make a right click on the legend and press **Convert to Graphics**. [image: convert to graphics]
   - then **ungroup** the symbol (*you have to do it a **several** times until you can actually access to the symbol properties*) and [image: arcmap ungroup]
   - change **manually the angle** of each symbol. [image: arcmap proporties]

---

The result could look like that:
[image: fix symbol angle]

Comment: I just read, that you don't want to use the manual way! So I guess that makes my answer unnecessary...